# How to create Ad-hoc wifi in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, wifi, adhoc

I'm looking forward to create an ad-hoc wifi connection within my application on an ipod touch. Is there any framework available to do this in a simple way? I have to use my appication within an environment where no wi-fi or internet connection is available but different devices have to communicate over tcp/ip.

Answer (score 1):

What you’re trying to do isn’t currently possible on iOS. Apps built with the SDK don’t get low-level-enough access to the Wi-Fi hardware to join or create networks, and the OS doesn’t let users create ad-hoc networks either. You might be able to wrangle Bluetooth into something useful here, but I wouldn’t bet on it.